# Why does this Cypher query only return one relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Why does this query return one result?

```
START n=node:node_auto_index(Name = 'Regular Users')  
MATCH (n)-[r:IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP*]->(v)  
WHERE v.Name = 'root'  
RETURN count(r) AS CountAllRelationships;
```

And why does this query return two results? All that I removed is the `(v)` and the `Where v.Name = Root`

```
START n=node:node_auto_index(Name = 'Regular Users')  
MATCH (n)-[r:IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP*]->() 
RETURN count(r) AS CountAllRelationships;
```

Here is the graph:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identifier "r" represents the collection of relationships on a matched path.

For the first query, there is only one path "Regular Users"->"All Principals"->"root" matched the query, and then there is one collection of relationships for the path returned as r, so the count(r) is 1.

For the second query, there are two paths matched the query, one is "Regular Users"->"All Principals", the other is "Regular Users"->"All Principals"->"root", so accordingly there are two collections of relationships returned, that's why the result of count(r) is 2.

Comment: Is there a way that one could return count as 2 if you specify the end end node like in query 1?

Comment: use length(r) instead of count(r). length(r) would return the number of elements in a collection, in this case the number of relationships in the collection r.

Comment: Awesome, does exactly what I needed it to do.